# replace text with condition in td jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace text in a td of a table, but with a specific condition, my table is generated dynamically with data of a DB, so there is no limit for the generation of the rows. Currently it only works with one row because of the id but I have tried with the getElementByClassName, but Google Chrome says that the function do not exist.

Here is my table code and my current JS Jquery code:

```
<table class="table" id="table_headers">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>
                    <th>Curso inscrito</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">Pagado</th>
                </tr>

                <?php 
                foreach($stmt->FetchAll() as $results) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<td>' . $results['name'] . " " . $results['first_last_name'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $results['user_email'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $results['user_course'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td id="user_pay">' . $results['user_pay'] . '</td>';
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
            </table>

    <script>

    var pay = document.getElementById("user_pay").innerText;
    if (pay == "0" ) {
        console.log(pay);
        $('#user_pay').html('No');
    }else if(pay == "1"){

        $('#user_pay').html('Si');
    }

</script>
```

Comment: can you try this `var pay = $(".user_pay");
$.each(pay, function() {
 var payvalue = $(this).text();
 if (payvalue == "0") {

  $(this).text("No")


 } else if (payvalue == "1") {

  $(this).text("Si")


 }



})` also use `class` instead of `ID`

Comment: It's `Element.getElementsByClassName(className)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jQuery way.
We take each element having "user_pay" class.
Regarding it's value, we edit its content.

(user_pay shall be a class, as id must be unique. So replace `id="user_pay"` by `class="user_pay"` in the PHP part of your code)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table_headers">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>
                    <th>Curso inscrito</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">Pagado</th>
                </tr>
<tr><td>name first_last_name</td><td>user_email</td><td>user_course</td><td class="user_pay">0</td></tr>

<tr><td>name first_last_name</td><td>user_email</td><td>user_course</td><td class="user_pay">1</td></tr>
<tr><td>name first_last_name</td><td>user_email</td><td>user_course</td><td class="user_pay">2</td></tr>
            </table>

    <script>

$(".user_pay").each(function( index ) {
    if ($( this ).text()=="0") {
        $( this ).html("No");
    } else if($( this ).text()=="1") {
        $( this ).html("Si");
    }
});
        
</script>
```

Comment: using a class...good form.  if an id is needed (for a db query etc), you can put an id on the row (tr).

Comment: Huge thanks for the help...i never thought using .each, now my project is almost done :D